# iOS app launching another app on Facebook login

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, swift

Installed in my iOS device, I have 5 personal apps (that is, developed by myself). Any app is related to a *single* Facebook app, that manages login for any of those apps. Problem is the following: when I try to login in one of the apps, the SO launches another app. Should any app be related to a different Facebook app?

[update] I think I solved, I found this one: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/troubleshooting#sharedappid

Comment: @Bhavin: could you please expand the concept?

Comment: did you use same fb appid that is used for other app??

Comment: Yes, I do use the same facebook id

Comment: then its only take the register bundle ID  which is register in facebook...

Answer (score 0):

Did you have the redirect url pointing to a app?
Each new app you make needs its own on facebook. It gets it own id and key.

Comment: On the FB side (the FB control panel), all the apps are "related"